# Prove every parallelogram preserving transformation can be constructed from an isometry and two stretches

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, transformation, affine-geometry

Prove that any transformation of the Euclidean plane which preserves parallelograms can be constructed from the composition of a rigid transformation (an isometry) and two [stretches](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Stretch.html), using synthetic geometry.

This fact is a direct result of the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) of a matrix.  However, this question is asking for a proof using synthetic geometry without coordinates or linear algebra.

(Source: https://mitpress.mit.edu/9780262010146/mathematics/  .  They in fact sketch a proof there, using synthetic geometry only, which I'm still trying to deconstruct and fill in.)

We can in fact assert more:

- Stretch 1 must have an invariant line perpendicular to that of Stretch 2
- Any line segment in the plane will be stretched by a scale factor in between that of Stretch 1 and 2

but I have not been able to use either of these facts to help with the proof.

Comment: I would use the image of a square to define the stretches. Then show that combining the transformation with the inverse of the stretches results in an isometry.